# Running A/B experiment only for new users in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

I'm trying to configure Firebase A/B experiment only for new users of my app.
What I did:

1) I set custom_first_open_time user param on the app first launch equal to timestamp in millis from epoch

2) I created a new experiment, set custom_first_open_time > 1581944923450 in the targeting section

3) I used 1 of 10 remote config params for the experiment. Once I started, all users stopped obtaining any remote config param and inside the app was used params set as default in code (inside the app). None of 10 params obtained in the app, though I change only 1 in A/B

Why using value of this param brakes the whole remote config?
Why it doesn't work as I expect?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I don't think these problems are related. Have you tried reproducing it in an empty sample app?

Comment: @michalbrz Thanks for your comment!
I've already solved the issue, the answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of using millis from epoch and looks like firebase couldn't compare so large numbers. Using just seconds solved the problem